# force app to open in a specific window

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks

I have recently set up dual monitors on my mac mini and am happy with the set up.

However applications such as the very useful Alfred or other applications automatically open up in the second display which is not the behavior I am looking for. Is there a method to allow the application to launch in the other display?

Comment: Are you asking about making an app that you write open in a chosen display, or making an app that someone else wrote open in a chosen display?  In the latter case, you should probably be asking on [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Ok thanks I will ask there